# Which typeface is used in moderncv?

Tags: fonts, moderncv

I am curious which typeface is used in the `moderncv` document class.

I wrote a CV with the following document class invocation:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
```

If I have to write a letter in a word processor, which font should I use to get the same font as `moderncv` with the `sans` option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `moderncv` document class uses the default fonts, namely Donald Knuth's [Computer Modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern). The `sans` option uses the sans serif variants of this typeface.

The [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) project has an extended version of these fonts in OpenType format. You can download them and install them in your operating system for use by other programs as usual.

Answer (score 4):

i think, it's lmodern (Latin Modern Sans).
You could use the Latin Modern Fonts for your word processor.

Answer (score 3):

Often your PDF reader will tell you which fonts are embedded within a pdf, usually in the document properties.

According to `evince` the font is `LMSans10-Regular` which is the `Latin Modern Sans` font.